# Two constructor calls inside one constructor in Java

Tags: java, constructor

Suppose the following situation:

```
class Foo{


    Foo(I i, I1 i1){

        super();
        this(i);
        ...
    }

    Foo(I i){
        super();
        ...
    }
}
```

Java complains that constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor. I cannot make two constructor calls to be first at the same time. Is there any workaround to this that wouldn't be repeating the code of the one-argument constructor inside the two argument constructor?

Comment: Why are you calling `super();` explicitely ? The call to the default parent constructor is automatically inserted at compilation anyways. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Comment: Even in an example seing variables named i and i1 brings chllls of fear on my back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as you mentioned in your comment , you don`t need to call super().
How does it works in Java ?

If you don`t write any constructor, than Java write to to you, when compiling your code and inserting:

```
public class Apple{
public Apple(){ // INJECTED BY JAVA,
   super();  // Object class
}
```

if you write a constructor, but don`t add anything than java replace yours:

```
public class Apple{
public Apple(){
   super();  // ADDED BY JAVA, during compiling
}
```

if you write your own:

```
public class Apple{
public Apple(){
   // init things and make the world a better place
}
```

in this case Java don`t insert anything, but super(); because it need to call the Object class as well. So, super(); actually will be there at all cost.

If you have multiple constructor calls, this() , than Java will add the super(); // Object class call at the top of your constructor.

Sources:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html
and 
http://www.amazon.co.uk/Programmer-Study-1Z0-803-1Z0-804-Oracle/dp/0071772006/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1435233062&sr=1-1&keywords=ocjp

Answer (score 4):

While I was typing my question, the answer came to my mind.  I don't need the call to `super` in the first constructor, since super is called in the one-argument constructor.

All I need to do is:

```
class Foo{

    Foo(I i, I1 i1){
        this(i);
        ... 
    }

    Foo(I i){
        super();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of that :p

Comment: I am trying to think of a weird situation where the super calls of the two constructors would be different and I would need another solution for this then.